# EF linq: order of where and select in single() query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Which query is optimized :

```
db.news.Select(c => new { c.Title, c.Date, c.ID })
       .SingleOrDefault(c => c.ID == 1);
```

or

```
db.news.Where(c => c.ID == 1)
       .Select(c => new { c.Title, c.Date })
       .SingleOrDefault();
```

I want this query:

```
select title, date  
where id = 1
```

in global which one is better `where` before `select`, or `where` after `select`?

Comment: I did not test this, but I am quite sure EF will build the same SQL query from both approaches.

Comment: And you can observe the generated SQL to confirm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework

Comment: @SomeBody one query need id in select and second one not

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay may problem is both of them not get that query

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `Where` before `Select` (`Where` first approach) is more performant, since it filters your result set first, and then executes `Select` for filtered values only.

Comment: EF builds a query based on all expressions prior to either a materializing operation (i.e. `ToList`, `AsEnumerable`, etc.) or encountering something that requires client-side evaluation and that feature is enabled.

Comment: Yet, I think Where first approach is performant. EF builds where first rapidly. However the performance difference between them, could be ignored for most of the applications.